# find out if value is in array then delete div with matching value in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

i searched for ages, I'm not good with arrays and functions in general.

lets say i have an array:

```
var arr = ["simple", "classic", "pro", "amat"];
```

what i want to do is to use jQuery to delete divs with matching ID's in the array.

How do i do this?

Comment: This is a very simple task. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var idSelector = '#' + arr.join(', #'); // "#simple, #classic, #pro, #amat"
$(idSelector).remove();
```

Docs:

- [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)
- [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove)

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple.

```
$(arr).each(function(){
    $("#" + this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Why not just `arr.forEach(function ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ufuzox/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$.each(arr, function(){
  $('#'+this).remove();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.

Comment: It would be useful if you explained why this is better than Praveen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example http://fiddle.jshell.net/3c2RP/1/

html:

```
<div id="simple">simple</div>
<div id="classic">classic</div>
<div id="pro">pro</div>
<div id="amat">amat</div>
<div id="strange">strange</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    var arr = ["simple", "classic", "pro", "amat"];
    $.each(arr,function(){
        $("#"+this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do it on clicking `body`?

Comment: He doesn't say when he want's do be the divs removed. I just give an example. I also created one more div so that only the ones in array are removed.

Comment: The author of the answer was faster. I removed the click here but not on fiddle.